# How to set up a local Ruby install in a user directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dreamhost

As Dreamhost has not been keeping up to date with their Ruby installation the support has suggested that I just compile it myself in my user directory and run it from there.

A fine suggestion so I have been attempting to do just that using the documentation here as a guide only:

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Ruby_on_Rails_Installation

The last time this guide seems to have been updated is 2009.

It's going pretty well except I am anticipating problems down the road because I noticed a number of the compiles were looking here:

> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/

This was causing some errors but for some reason no fails. But obviously what I would rather would be if everything I run were to be looking here for everything gem related:

> /home/tribey/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0

Examining my PATH I see that it's pointing up to the old place.

```
[dwalin]$ $PATH
-bash: /home/tribey/local/bin:/home/tribey/usr/bin/:/home/tribey/usr/share/:/home/tribey/.gems/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why `/usr/games` is in there either. I don't know if this is why the compile of rubygems was looking there. Looking at my `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` does not provide any answers.

Can anyone tell me where these paths are being set so I can change them? If anyone can offer any other suggestions or advice please feel free.

Thank you!

This is the website that I am setting this up under which at the moment is dumping alot of information about the environment.

http://www.devweb.org/

Comment: I would highly recommend using RVM http://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: And I would recommend [RBENV](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), [here](http://rubyforadmins.com/installation) is a quick howto.